# vba code to change all cells to absolute references

Tags: excel, vba

i have this vba code that i thought would replace each formula so that the cell is absolute (ie $f$12 instead of f12). Does anyone have any recommendations to my code? I appear to get '#VALUES' for most of the cells.

```
Sub Absolute()
    Dim cl As Range    
    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)              
        cl.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(cl.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, True)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which formulas returned `#VALUES` and which did not?

Comment: Try `xlAbsolute` instead `true` as 4th parameter

Comment: What is `xlA1`? Where does that get defined?